# Unable to get asp.net element Text property with JQuery

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I have an asp.net repeater that's creating an unordered list of Hyperlink objects. I'm trying to use Jquery to capture the "Text" value of a given hyperlink for nefarious purposes to come later.

Here's the repeater creating my list o' links:

```
<ul class="links">
    <asp:Repeater Runat="server" ID="_items" EnableViewState="false">
        <ItemTemplate>

            <li>
                <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" Text='[Eval]' NavigateUrl="#" onclick="return aClick();" />
            </li><br />

        </ItemTemplate>
   </asp:Repeater>
</ul>
```

...and the Javascript for that aClick() function:

```
function aClick() {
    alert("Click " + $(this).text());
    return false;
}
```

All I get when this runs is an alert box which reads "Click ". No text from the object that called the function is returned (and yes, all my links do have text.)

I have tried event.target per Jquery docs, I have tried event.srcElement (even though I'm using Chrome), and I've tried moving $(this).text() to a separate variable at the start of the function and then referencing the variable in my alert. I've tried Jquery 1.8.2 and 1.11.2. Nothing.

I see from the dev tools that $(this) is referring to the global Window, not the object that triggered the event, so it's clear I need help figuring out how to correct this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` is not retained on the function call from an inline `onclick` handler. You need to pass it:

Use this:

```
onclick="return aClick(this);"
```

and

```
function aClick(link) {
    console.log("Click " + $(link).text());
    return false;
}
```

When using jQuery I strongly recommend you do not use inline handlers, as they separate the handler registration code from the handler for no good reason. Use jQuery event handlers instead for easier maintenance:

e.g.

```
$(function(){
   $('.links a').click(function(){
      console.log("Click " + $(this).text());
      return false;
   }
});
```

**Notes:**

- `$(function(){...});` is just a shortcut for `$(document).ready(function(){...});`
- Do not use `alert` in debugging `click` events (it just gets in the way). Use `console.log` instead (but remember to remove them for release as non-debug IE will crash as console is not defined unless you have the debug tools running).

If you want to support dynamic elements, change it to be a *delegated event handler*, connected to the non-changing ancestor, using `on` like this:

```
$(function(){
   $('.links').on('click', 'a', function(){
      console.log("Click " + $(this).text());
      return false;
   }
});
```

This supports links added later and has a lower overhead (only one handler connected at startup) and any extra delay at event time is unnoticeable as you simple cannot click 50,000 times a second :)

Comment: Thanks for clearing this up. Both your exmples work, but unfortunately the second (with the handler included in the '$(function() {' area) returns a double click event -- alert window opens, I click ok, second alert window opens. This function is going to drive a toggle, so I can't have that happening. Anyway, bottom line is the issue is resolved.

Comment: @bmurrell30: I should also have advised to use `console.log` for debugging click events and not `alert` :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('[id$=_items]').find('[id*= HyperLink1]').click(function(event){
   alert($(this).text());
});
```